# Adding object mappings for NHibernate not working

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I am setting up a .Net MVC WebApplication with NHibernate 4.
All my models are in a separate project and I am trying to add all these class mappings. The problem is that the mappings are not added.
Here is my code:

```
        var cfg = new Configuration().DataBaseIntegration(db =>
        {
            db.ConnectionStringName = <ConnectionName>;
            db.Dialect<NHibernate.Dialect.MsSql2012Dialect>();
        });

        var mapper = new ModelMapper();
        var types = typeof(MyObject).Assembly.GetTypes().Where(t => t.GetCustomAttributes().Any(attr => attr is ClassAttribute classAttribute)).ToList();
        mapper.AddMappings(types);
        HbmMapping domainMapping = mapper.CompileMappingForAllExplicitlyAddedEntities();
        cfg.AddMapping(domainMapping);
        cfg.BuildMappings();
        SessionFactory = cfg.BuildSessionFactory();
```

`types` contains all the correct mappings but apparently `mapper.AddMappings(types);` does not correctly bind them. `cfg.ClassMappings` contains `0` entries.

I have read numerous examples but they use the same approach to add these mappings.

When adding the mapping for each type explicitly using the following code:

```
foreach(var type in types)
{
    mapper.AddMapping(type);
}
```

I get the following exception: System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'The mapping class must be an implementation of IConformistHoldersProvider.
Parameter name: type'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are using attributes mapping via `NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes` nuget package.

In this case instead of calling `modelMapper.AddMappings` you need to add mappings as explained [here](https://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#mapping-attributes-howto). Something like:

```
  // Instead of modelMapper.AddMappings use this:
  cfg.AddInputStream(
    NHibernate.Mapping.Attributes.HbmSerializer.Default.Serialize(
       typeof(MyObject).Assembly));

    // Now you can use this configuration to build your SessionFactory...
```

`ModelMapper` class is needed and works only for Mapping ByCode (as namespace `NHibernate.Mapping.ByCode` suggests).

Answer (score 1):

Not sure but you might be getting types those are not actually a `ClassMapping`. That is what your exception is saying:

> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: 'The mapping class must be an implementation of IConformistHoldersProvider. Parameter name: type'

Just filter the list as below:

```
var types = typeof(MyObject).Assembly.GetTypes()
.Where
(t => 
    t.BaseType != null && 
    t.BaseType.IsGenericType &&
    t.BaseType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(ClassMapping<>)
);

var modelMapper = new ModelMapper();
modelMapper.AddMappings(types);
HbmMapping hbmMapping = modelMapper.CompileMappingForAllExplicitlyAddedEntities();
configuration.AddMapping(hbmMapping);
configuration.BuildMappings();
```